# Get all numeric strings from SQLite Column and get total sum calculation

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am new in Android and in SQLite. I have a column "AMOUNT" of just numbers in SQLite which I am able to show in a ListView. But I can't get any way that I understand to add them all and show in a TextView.

Here is the database Helper

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "people.db";
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "people_table";
    private static final String COL1 = "ID";
    private static final String COL2 = "DATE";
    private static final String COL3 = "DESCRIPTION";
    private static final String COL4 = "AMOUNT";


    DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String createTable = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                " DATE TEXT, DESCRIPTION TEXT, AMOUNT TEXT)";
        db.execSQL(createTable);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public boolean addData(String inc_date, String inc_description, String inc_amount){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COL2, inc_date);
        contentValues.put(COL3, inc_description);
        contentValues.put(COL4, inc_amount);

        long result  = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);

        return result != -1;
    }

    public Cursor showData(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        return db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME, null);
    }

    public boolean updateData(String id, String name, String email, String tvShow){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COL1,id);
        contentValues.put(COL2,name);
        contentValues.put(COL3,email);
        contentValues.put(COL4,tvShow);
        db.update(TABLE_NAME, contentValues, "ID = ?", new String[] {id});
        return true;
    }

    public Integer deleteData(String id){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        return db.delete(TABLE_NAME, "ID = ?", new String[] {id});
    }

}
```

And here is the Activity

```
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class IncPag extends AppCompatActivity {

    DatabaseHelper peopleDB;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.inc_pag);
        all_inc_dat();
        amo_sum();
    }

    private void all_inc_dat(){
        TextView inc_data=findViewById(R.id.tex_inc);
        ListView dat_col=findViewById(R.id.dat_col);
        ListView des_col=findViewById(R.id.des_col);
        ListView amo_col=findViewById(R.id.amo_col);
        peopleDB=new DatabaseHelper(this);

        Cursor data = peopleDB.showData();

        if (data.getCount() == 0) {
            inc_data.setText(R.string.no_data_found);
            return;
        }
        ArrayList<String> dat_lis = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> des_lis = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> amo_lis = new ArrayList<>();

        while (data.moveToNext()) {
            dat_lis.add(data.getString(data.getColumnIndex( "DATE")));
            des_lis.add(data.getString(data.getColumnIndex( "DESCRIPTION")));
            amo_lis.add(data.getString(data.getColumnIndex( "AMOUNT")));

        }

        ListAdapter dat_ada = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, dat_lis);
        dat_col.setAdapter(dat_ada);
        ListAdapter des_ada = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, des_lis);
        des_col.setAdapter(des_ada);
        ListAdapter amo_ada = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, amo_lis);
        amo_col.setAdapter(amo_ada);
    }

    private void amo_sum(){
        TextView tv_sum=findViewById(R.id.tv_sum);
        tv_sum.setText(amount total?);
    }
}
```

If its easier to calculate within the Database helper then show me a SQLite solution. or if its easier to do calculation after getting on listview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution Part 1

You could add the following method to the database helper

```
public long getAmountSum(){
    long rv = 0;
    String[] columns = new String[]{"sum(" + COL4 + ")"};
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor csr = db.query(TABLE_NAME,columns,null,null,null,null,null);
    if (csr.moveToFirst()) {
        rv = csr.getLong(0);
    }
    csr.close();
    return rv;
}
```

- Note if a value in the AMOUNT column is not a valid integer then it will be given a value of 0 for that row.
- This equates to running the query `SELECT sum(AMOUNT) FROM people_table;` but uses the SQLiteDatabase **query** convenience method as opposed to using the **rawQuery** method.

  - It is considered better practice to use the convenience methods when they can be used, as opposed to using the rawQuery method.
  - It is also considered better practice to use a single source for table and column names rather than hard coding column names each time they are used (hence the use of `COL4` rather than `"AMOUNT"`).
  - Although using hard coded column offsets (e.g. **`0`** in the above), the above is an exception where the actual column name (i.e. **`sum(AMOUNT)`**), as it is derived from the underlying generated SQL, could be more problematic coding it than coding the column offset (first/only column so it will always be 0).
- If there are no rows in the table then 0 will be returned.

### Solution Part 2

The above could be used in conjunction with an amended **`amo_sum`** method as per :-

```
private void amo_sum(){
    TextView tv_sum=findViewById(R.id.tv_sum);
    tv_sum.setText(String.valueOf(peopleDB.getAmountSum));
}
```

- Note the above is in-principle code and has not been tested so may contain some errors.

Comment: Thank you. it works. Except two () after csr.moveToFirst and peopleDB.getAmountSum

Comment: Answer corrected accordingly. Could you please tick the question as answered.