# How to Get sum of SQLite Column of Same Date

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have a SQLite database with 4 columns:

> COL1=ID
>
> COL2=DATE
>
> COL3=DESCRIPTION
>
> COL4=AMOUNT

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52232087/get-all-numeric-strings-from-sqlite-column-and-get-total-sum-calculation) before and got a way to get the SUM of the Amount Column. like this:

```
public long get_tot_inc() {
    long rv = 0;
    String[] columns = new String[]{"sum(" + COL4 + ")"};
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor csr = db.query(TABLE_NAME, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
    if (csr.moveToFirst()) {
        rv = csr.getLong(0);
    }
    csr.close();
    return rv;
}
```

But now I am showing a ListView based on same date supplied via string using code like this:

```
public Cursor get_amo_by_date(String dat) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT " + COL4 + " FROM " + TABLE_NAME +
            " WHERE " + COL2 + " = '" + dat + "'";
    return db.rawQuery(query, null);
}
```

I need to get sum of this new ListView. If possible please give me a method to do calculations by retrieving data in int then do calculation in Activity. Although if SQLite is easier give me that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this will work for you

```
public int calculateAmountByDate(String dat)
    {
        int sum=0;
        Cursor cur = db.rawQuery( "SELECT SUM( " + COL4 + ") FROM " + TABLE_NAME +
                " WHERE " + COL2 + " = '" + dat + "'", null);
        if(cur.moveToFirst())
        {
            sum= cur.getInt(0);
        }
        return sum;
    }
```

it will return value in integer.

```
int amount=calculateAmountByDate("Pass your Date here");
```

show this value to the view.

Answer (score -1):

```
public Cursor get_amo_by_date(String dat) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT " + COL4 + " FROM " + TABLE_NAME +
            " WHERE " + COL2 + " = '" + dat + "'";
    return db.rawQuery(query, null);
}
```

this is right as i think

Comment: that's just providing data to the listview. I need the new amount column sum populated with that code

Comment: Just add a `, Count(*) AS DateCount,` to that query